# Memory Error when loading a txt file for an ML model

Tags: transformer, python-3.x, pipelines, memory

I am trying to run the Python code below:

```
from transformers import pipeline


question_answerer = pipeline("question-answering", model='distilbert-base-uncased-distilled-squad')

with open('output_file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:

    context = file.read()

    question = input("Type your question: ")

    print("Calculating answer, please wait.")

    result = question_answerer(question=question, context=context)

    print(f"Answer: '{result['answer']}', score: {round(result['score'], 4)}, start: {result['start']}, end: {result['end']}")
```

but I get `MemoryError`, since the input text file is too large (>100GB).

Are there any techniques to read such files?

I can imagine there are others with the same issue. What is a standard approach in situations as such?

Comment: This question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396238/memory-error-due-to-the-huge-input-file-size

Comment: @AmitKeinan I am afraid it won't do in my case.